# Will a compiled vb6 application theoretically work under WINE on Mac?

Tags: vb6, emulation, wine

Another developer at work told me it wouldn't work for some reason specific to Visual Basic 6 applications.

But I think it should work as long as you include the correct DLLs and runtime files, isn't VB6 compiled to machine code?

EDIT: I just mean in general should it be possible. I'm going to actually test this out in a few days as long as nobody gives me a theoretical reason it won't work.

EDIT 2: I think the developer was referring to P-code, which vb6 can optionally compile to instead of binary which runs under a virtual machine similar to (or the precursor of) the .Net framework.

Comment: VB6 can be compiled to machine code or P-code, it's an option under the project settings. Theoretically I think it *might* work, but personally I wouldn't want to support it myself.

Comment: Is not the default for a vb6 app to generate machine code? Does it run under a virtual machine or something otherwise? I thought it was machine code in the EXE and DLL and windows system calls.

Comment: Here's the [manual topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240843.aspx) which explains how to change the settings. I think the default is p-code. Microsoft always described http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240840(VS.60).aspx p-code as an interpreted language, possibly you could think of it as a virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested a large VB6 app in Wine under Ubuntu. Event the msi installer worked fine. Had some troubles with low-level implementation details (e.g. in NM_CUSTOMDRAW on CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW phase the hDC text is not transparent by default as in Windows common controls). So yes, even heavily subclassed stuff works. I just had to iron those minor glitches.

Here is a function that checks if app is running under wine

```
Property Get IsWine() As Boolean
    IsWine = (GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "wine_get_unix_file_name") <> 0)
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think there was a theoretical reason for it not to work based on my understanding of WINE. And if we can get the installer and basic program working I can write custom code for the version under WINE where needed with your code as long as most of the core functionality works.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7361

It looks like you can get most VB6 programs to work.

Comment: Great link, thanks. As long as I know it can be done I'll give it a try...Ultimately I have access to both the source code and the deployment environment so I just need to be willing to spend the time investment.